# Custom fields not available when doing CSV import

Tags: custom-fields, import, data-import

Tried creating several custom field sets but none of the fields are showing up in the match fields window?

Comment: Hi Paul - have you set those fields as Searchable? (which is a poorly explained requirement for imports imo)

Comment: good to know Pete!